# How to search intelligently for something within context? Is there a larger topic involved?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to build a site that searches a database of user comments for the most often mentioned names of movies. However, with certain movie titles like Up and Warrior(2011), there are far too many irrelevant results and I want to only search for the title in threads about movies or else make sure it's mentioned in the right context. Is there a more generalized question that this problem is a subset of (I'm sure there is but google yielded nothing so far).

Comment: You mean that with search in databases you don't find only movie title with these key words? You might see GATE tool [link](http://gate.ac.uk).

Comment: Correct, there are lots of false positives with common words like Up. Thank you for the link I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

working out the context of a chunk of text to determin whether the word "up" is refering to a film or not is, unfortunately,  something only a human can do at the moment.

have a look at amazon's mechanical turk service, you can pay people to search thru the text for you. this might not be great if you are trying to offer a free service however.